# The component metadata for "Oracle Destination" could not be upgraded to the newer version of the component

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis

I'm trying to tranfer data from Microsoft SQL Server to Oracle by SSIS.
- Microsoft SQL Server 2017.
- Oracle 11g.
- Microsoft Visual Studio 2019.

If I set TargetServerVersion = SQL Server 2019, it's working.
[image: TargetServerVersion = SQL Server 2019]

If I set TargetServerVersion = SQL Server 2016, it's not working.
[image: TargetServerVersion = SQL Server 2016]

```
SSIS package "C:\~Akkapolki\Project\Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019\MicrosoftSQLServerToOracle\MicrosoftSQLServerToOracle\MicrosoftSQLServerToOracle.dtsx" starting.
Error: 0xC004801F at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: The component metadata for "Oracle Destination, clsid {4F885D04-B578-47B7-94A0-DE9C7DA25EE2}" could not be upgraded to the newer version of the component. The PerformUpgrade method failed.
Information: 0x4004300A at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Validation phase is beginning.
Error: 0xC001000E at MicrosoftSQLServerToOracle: The connection "{2739438E-C724-491F-8846-4777F0F7EEE3}" is not found. This error is thrown by Connections collection when the specific connection element is not found.
Error: 0xC004800B at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Cannot find the connection manager with ID "{2739438E-C724-491F-8846-4777F0F7EEE3}" in the connection manager collection due to error code 0xC0010009. That connection manager is needed by "Oracle Destination.Connections[MSOraConnection]" in the connection manager collection of "Oracle Destination". Verify that a connection manager in the connection manager collection, Connections, has been created with that ID.
Error: 0xC0047017 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Oracle Destination failed validation and returned error code 0xC004800B.
Error: 0xC004700C at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: One or more component failed validation.
Error: 0xC0024107 at Data Flow Task: There were errors during task validation.
SSIS package "C:\~Akkapolki\Project\Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019\MicrosoftSQLServerToOracle\MicrosoftSQLServerToOracle\MicrosoftSQLServerToOracle.dtsx" finished: Failure.
The program '[82392] DtsDebugHost.exe: DTS' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Oracle Destination component.
[image: Oracle Destination component]

Comment: Which version of SSIS are you using ?

Comment: @AmiraBedhiafi, I think 2017 since I installed from SQLServer2017-SSEI-Dev.

Comment: Check this : https://support.microsoft.com/fr-tn/help/2713827/fix-dataflow-ssispackagename-error-when-you-try-to-open-an-ssis-packag

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: Have you resolved it? Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Connector you installed for SSIS only works from 2019, if you need to work for earlier versions you need to install additional attunity connectors.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/oracle-connector?view=sql-server-ver15#installation

For Sql server 2016, download and install AttunitySSISOraAdaptersSetupX64.msi from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52950

Comment: Try to add relevant content from the link for additional information.